# QGIS - How do I upscale resolution of raster data from 500mx500m to 100mx100m?

Tags: qgis, raster, modis, resolution

I have a raster file that is derived from MODIS which gives 500mx500m resolution and want to change the resolution to 100mx100m. The issue is when I look at the properties of the file it only gives the pixel values, how do I figure out what pixel values would correspond to 100mx100m?

[image]

Comment: I guess that your image is in EPSG:4326 coordinate system and the pixel size is in degrees. If you need square pixels with size 100x100 meters you must also reproject the raster into some other coordinate system that is using meters as unit and is otherwise suitable for your data.

Comment: Asserting Cartesian distance for all column widths in a geographic coordinate system is an exercise in willful ignorance. There's an implicit, "Well, not really, but you know what I mean..." built in. Therefore, you can increase uncompressed size by a factor of 25 just by dividing the existing dimensions by five.